# Add a secondary label to a plot x-axis for events

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I have an ax.stackplot showing population of different groups over time. The x-axis is time and the y-axis is population. I am showing time at major labels 1 year and minor labels 1 month, however, changes in the data occur more frequently at "events". I'd like to show labels for these events along the x-axis, kind of how I have it sketched out in the image here:
[image]

I've attempted adding a second axis with `plt.axes()`, but this second axis is overwriting the ticks of my first axis for some reason. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: `plt.axes()` does not create a new axes if there is already one present.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, the solution was to use ax.twiny() to create a second axes object, I then specified the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many points, I think the best way to do this is adding text to your axes using `ax.text`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

# Random plot
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

# ax.text(x, y, text, rotation)
ax.text(0, -0.35, "Event 1", rotation=90)  # rotation=90 is easier to read, for me
ax.text(0.5, -0.35, "Event 2", rotation=-90)  # opposite rotation
ax.text(0.75, -0.35, "Event 3", rotation=-90)

# This gives some space at the bottom of the figure
# so that the text is visible
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

pyplot.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Check the [Axes.text documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, I was able to come up with a solution based on your suggestions. The solution involves using ax.twiny() to create a second axes object, and then specifying the second x-axis data points and labels. Below is a simple example for those interested:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# Create some meaningless data for testing.
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.full(10, len(x))

# Set up figure and set axes parameters.
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]))

# Get a second axes (for secondary labels) and set parameters.
axl = ax.twiny()
axl.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=True, labelbottom=True, labeltop=False, top=False, length=15, colors=[.5,.5,.5])

# Plot data on primary axes
ax.bar(x, y)
interval = ax.xaxis.get_view_interval()

# Set label properties on secondary axes (for secondary labels)
axl.xaxis.set_view_interval(*interval)
axl.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['a', 'b'])
axl_loc = ticker.FixedLocator([0.5, 4.75])
axl.xaxis.set_major_locator(axl_loc)

plt.show()
```

[image]